# configMap and secret - priority

Tags: kubernetes

I didn't find any information about priority of configMaps vs secrets. If I have the same keys in both, which one wins?

Here's an example of a template:

```yaml
spec:
  containers:
  - envFrom:
    - configMapRef:
      name: my-configmap
    - secretRef:
      name: my-secret
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the kubernetes [code](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/ea0764452222146c47ec826977f49d7001b0ea8c/staging/src/k8s.io/client-go/applyconfigurations/core/v1/container.go#L118), it iterates over the list in sequence.

```golang
func (b *ContainerApplyConfiguration) WithEnvFrom(values ...*EnvFromSourceApplyConfiguration) *ContainerApplyConfiguration {
    for i := range values {
.
.
```

So the order matters, whatever comes later in the list will overwrite the previous value. In the example you provided, the value from `my-secret` will win.

Comment: Cool, thanks for the code excerpt and the explanation!